# iphone coredata setValue not working inside if statement

Tags: iphone, core-data, if-statement

I have my coredata working fine, but when I put a setValue inside an if, it doesn't work,

this is the code>

```
-(void) salvalo {

StaffManagerAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
NSManagedObject *newDay;
newDay = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"DaysAttendance"
                                       inManagedObjectContext:context];

[newDay setValue:startday forKey:@"start"];
[newDay setValue:today forKey:@"datef"];
[newDay setValue:myNumber forKey:@"empID"]; 
[newDay setValue:myNumber2 forKey:@"intID"];
//[newDay setValue:internet forKey:@"sinch"];


NSError *error;
[context save:&error];

if ([internet isEqualToString:@"YES"] ) {
    [self insertJson];

    [newDay setValue:internet forKey:@"sinch"];

}
else {
    [newDay setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"sinch"];

}



//[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];


      }
```

please note that when I use the code inside the if in the commented part

> //[newDay setValue:internet forKey:@"sinch"];

, it saves normally that value (YES/NO) to the coredata, but inside the if, it doesnt work, even if I put al the delegate and context stuff inside the if,,

so what is the problem? how to fix it?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `[context save:&error];` is  before the if statements.

You may be setting the new value properly, just not saving.  The problem might just be this oversight.

Comment: duhhh,  thanks a lot!!, that's what happens after hours of work!, the simple slips haha, cheers!